Is there a way to link PL/SQL Developer 15.0.4 with Oracle Client 11g?
I ran into this issue when starting PL/SQL Developer:

The reason seems to be that the underlying Oracle_Client 12c MUI instance is FUBAR. As in, even the C:\Software\Oracle\... folder wasn't there anymore.
Our sys admins have looked into this and they tried to reinstall it but they failed.
So (for now?) they have installed the Oracle Client 11g version, which means I now have folder with path:
C:\Software\oracle\product\11.2.0
Containing:
client_32
client_64
Which contains the needed oci.dll file in the bin folder.
PL/SQL Developer 15.0.4 seems to be fixed to look for the 12.2.0 path, as visible in the above screenshot.
Looking into the registry seems to confirm this because under
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle
I only find KEY_OraClient12Home1 which contains a lot of paths like C:\Software\Oracle\product\12.2.0\client_64 (and similar variants)
It seems it is only possible to install the latest version of the PL/SQL Developer:

That's on this url:
https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/free-trial/
My question

How do I solve this discrepancy between Oracle and PL / SQL Developer
client versions?


What's up with the closing thing lately, seriously. I have provided all the info I can and it was answered. Don't just close because you don't understand the question.

You can try to configure it to point to the new Oracle Home/bin in the windows PATH Environment + adjust the the configuration in the Software preferences like in the information provided:
https://forums.allroundautomations.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=37996

That did it! It's Configuration > Preferences by now but setting home and library location worked.
